# LaTeXit show just the first page

Tags: latexit

I'm a beginer in Latex and I like to learn about it, as I'm user Mac, I installed LaTeXit, but I have multiple problems.

I begin to write in the editor area, but I just get the first page of the document, I don't know why.

Here an screenshoot:
I don't see the second part, even when I export the document.

I just simply follow an tutorial, but that it doesn't work.

[image]

Here my config:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{First document}
\author{User}
\date{2017-01-01}
```

Preambles config.

And in the Body config, I have:

```
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! LaTeXit is supposed to be used only to typeset single equations which can be used in other software, e.g. Keynote/Powerpoint. If you are looking for a "full-time" editor, use TeXShop which also comes with the installation of MacTeX.

Comment: LaReXiT is meant to be used for short snippets and as an equation editor. It is NOT meant for producing full documents. Try using TeXShop which is also installed by MacTeX an found in `/Applications/TeX`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This editor (as @Herb Schulz and @hakaze mentioned) isn't meant to be used for full latex documents, so you can try [TexShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/index.html) or take a look to this question

[LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)